# Function with first argument being optional and dynamic

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have a function

```
 functionName(...arrayOfArguments, { test:"test }){}
```

Sometimes I have `arrayOfArguments` but sometimes it is just `null`. I would like to make this function dynamic so if `arrayOfArguments` has any length it should look like above but if `arrayOfArguments` is null I would like to do not pass it and just pass second argument like:

```
 functionName({ test:"test }){}
```

How can I make it dynamic so it will pass array if it exists but will not pass this first argument if it doesn't?

If I just do:

```
functionName(...arrayOfArguments, { test:"test }){}
```

and `arrayOfArguments` is null it will just pass null there as a first argument. How can I define those arguments?

Comment: Then take care that `arrayOfArguments` isn't `null` but `[]`?

Comment: As far as I know, if your function has two arguments, you will always need both arguments.

Comment: please add the part where you call the function and the part of the definition of the signature of the function.

Comment: Please correct the basic syntax errors in your examples (quotes, and are those meant to be *calls* or *declarations*?).

Answer (score 1):

If `arrayofArguments` is `null`, you can't use iterable spread on it; you'll have to use `arrayOfArguments ?? []` to make the call in order to avoid an error. That will result in **no** arguments for that array being passed to `functionName` (followed by the object with the `test` property).

So that means one option is that the function should expect zero or more arguments followed by the object with the `test` property argument at the end. You can define `functionName` to support that by gathering up all of its arguments into an array then popping the object off the end of the array:

```js
function functionName(...theArray) {
    const obj = theArray.pop();
    console.log(`theArray has ${theArray.length} elements; obj.test = ${obj.test}`);
}

function example(arrayOfArguments) {
    functionName(...arrayOfArguments ?? [], { test:"test" });
}

example(null);
example([]);
example(["a"]);
example(["a", "b"]);
```

Another option is to move the object at the end to the beginning. You still need `?? []`, but it makes the function a bit simpler:

```js
function functionName(obj, ...theArray) {
    console.log(`theArray has ${theArray.length} elements; obj.test = ${obj.test}`);
}

function example(arrayOfArguments) {
    functionName({ test:"test" }, ...arrayOfArguments ?? []);
}

example(null);
example([]);
example(["a"]);
example(["a", "b"]);
```

Finally, you could just pass `arrayOfArguments` into the function directly, rather than spreading it out:

```js
function functionName(theArray, obj) {
    console.log(`theArray ${theArray ? `has ${theArray.length} elements` : "is null"}; obj.test = ${obj.test}`);
}

function example(arrayOfArguments) {
    functionName(arrayOfArguments, { test:"test" });
}

example(null);
example([]);
example(["a"]);
example(["a", "b"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be two parameters? I think you could handle this scenario using an object parameter as the following:

```js
const functionName = ({ arrayOfArguments, testParam }) => {
    if (arrayOfArguments != undefined && arrayOfArguments != null) {
        // code if arrayOfArguments is defined and not null
    } else {
        // code if arrayOfArguments is either undefined or null
    }

    console.log('arrayOfArguments', arrayOfArguments);
    console.log('testParam', testParam);
};

functionName({ testParam: { "test": "test" } });
functionName({ arrayOfArguments: null, testParam: { "test": "test" } });
functionName({ arrayOfArguments: ['a', 'b'], testParam: { "test": "test" } });
```

If handling a single object parameter does not fit your requirement then evaluating for a null (and/or undefined) `arrayOfArguments` like [@deceze mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711527/function-with-first-argument-being-optional-and-dynamic#comment128434683_72711527) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a public function that accepts the array and inside of this function you can declare a private function which is the one with the logic.

```js
function publicFn(array) {
    const privateFn = (obj, nestedArray) => console.log(`array with ${nestedArray.length} elements and the obj.test === ${obj.test}`);
    privateFn({ test: "test" }, array || []);
}

publicFn();
publicFn(null);
publicFn([]);
publicFn(["a"]);
publicFn(["b"]);
publicFn(["a", "b"]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```